# xdotool type all in uppercase

Tags: xdotool

I have installed `xdotool` (version 3.20150503.1) in Ubuntu Server 16.04 "Xenial Xerus" LTS (64bits). When I send the command:

```
xdotool type test
```

The result is:

```
TEST
```

The same with `xdotool keydown shift type test`, and by manually pressing the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key.

I used `xdotool` in Raspbian and had no problem with it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the keyboard language settings. I was connecting via remote desktop to XFCE, I just had to change the keyboard to Spanish and xdotool started working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Execute `setxkbmap` before execute `xdotool`
Quote from https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/97

For example: `setxkbmap us && xdotool type "Hello!"`